# Unset array key if value is empty

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 2
            [price] => 15
            [processor] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [processor_id] => 3
                            [price] => 15
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [processor_id] => 4
                            [price] => 15
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 3
            [price] => 15
            [processor] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [processor_id] => 3
                            [price] => 15
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [processor_id] => 4
                            [price] => 15
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [processor] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => // empty value
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => // empty value
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have this array, Now I want to unset the array which array doesn't have any value like in the last array there is no value given so I want to unset the whole array key.

In This array, i have empty value so how can i unset the [4] key. So is it possible without foreach loop.

Comment: do it with foreach and do unset or array_splice

Comment: Yes do it. What have you tried so far? Where did a problem occur? Can you describe this problem? Currently you are merely asking for someone to do your job.

Comment: There is no built-in function to do this, so you will ultimately have to use a loop (probably recursive) in some way or another (hidden or visible). Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks @JeesKDenny  i got solution with your idea. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this. As you supplied no code I recommend reading the documentation on php.net.

```
function filter_function($var) {
    // return an expression evaluating to true to keep value
    return ($var["option_id"]);
}

$filtered = array_filter($unfiltered, "filter_function");
```